# CloudWatch Metric Filter for checking JSON key exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to come up with a metric filter expression that filters CloudWatch Logs when a special JSON key attribute is present.

Use case is the following: the application does all kinds of logging(in JSON format) and whenever it has a special JSON key(nested JSON response from third-part service), I would like to filter it.

Example logs:

```jsonl
{"severity":"INFO","msg":"EVENT","event":{"key1":"value1"}}
{"severity":"INFO","msg":"FooService responded","response":{"response_code":800}}
```

Filter patterns that I've tried that don't work:

```
{ $.response }
{ $.response = *}
{ $.response = "*"}
{ $.response EXISTS }
{ $.response IS TRUE }
{ $.response NOT NULL }
{ $.response != NULL }
```

Expected filtering result:

```jsonl
{"severity":"INFO","msg":"FooService responded","response":{"response_code":800}}
```

---

`{ $.response EXISTS }` does the opposite of what I expect(returns the 1st line rather than then 2nd) but I'm not sure how to negate it.

Reference material: [Filter and pattern syntax @ CloudWatch User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found a good solution.

But I did find one at least.

If you search for a key being `!=` a specific value, it seems to do a null check on it.

So if you say:

```
{$.response != "something_no_one_should_have_ever_saved_this_response_as"}
```

Then you get all entries where `response` exists in your json, and where it's not your string (hopefully all of the valid entries)

Definitly not a clean solution, but it seems to be pretty functional

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to the task of finding records where a field exists. Indeed, the [linked document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) in the question specifically calls this out as not supported.

**but**

If we simply reverse our logic this becomes a more tractable problem. Looking at your data, you want `All records where there's a response key` but that could also be stated as `All records where there isn't an events key`.

This means you could accomplish the task with `{$.event NOT EXISTS}`. Of course, this becomes more complicated the more types of log messages you get (I had to chain three different `NOT EXISTS` queries for my use case) but it does solve the problem.

Comment: Of course, using Cloudwatch insights gives you more query flexibility and is a better answer but I didn't have access at the time!