# AWS CloudWatch Logs Metric Filter Pattern For NOT NULL values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

**Background**
Documentation for AWS CloudWatch Metric Filter Patterns seems to be pretty light. This seems to be the only source out there:

`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html`

Looking at the above page, it seems that you can search for fields that are null values & you can search for missing fields but you can't search for fields that are present but are not null.

For example, here's log that i'm pushing to cloudwatch:

```
{
     "userId": "my_user",
     "externalUserId": null,
     "logDirection": "INBOUND",
     "type": "RESPONSE",
     "layerIdentifier": "my_id"
}
```

I want to create a metric for every event that has "exernalUserId" not set to null.

I can do:
{ $.externalUserId IS NULL }  this will match the above event

```
 { $.externalUserId = * }  this will also match the above event

 { $.externalUserId != "blah" }  this will also match the above event
```

What I want to do is:

```
{ $.externalUserId IS NOT NULL }, this gives me an invalid syntax error

{ $.externalUserId != "null" }, this matches the above event (which I don't want)

{ $.externalUserId != null }, this gives me an invalid syntax error
```

**Question**
Is it possible to filter for events where the externalUserId value is not set to null? i.e. I want to find events where this value is a string

tried all of the above, was hoping for a filter pattern that hits non null field values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CloudWatch Metric Filter for checking JSON key exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755071/cloudwatch-metric-filter-for-checking-json-key-exists)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your patterns with [the "hidden" CloudWatch Metric Filter Debugger](https://dev.to/aws-builders/the-hidden-cloudwatch-metric-filter-debugger-2efc). It looks to me like your question contains patterns that do work for your problem.

I expanded your test data into two lines. The first line has a `null` at the key we're querying on. The second has a string.

```
{"userId": "my_user","externalUserId": null,"logDirection": "INBOUND", "type": "RESPONSE","layerIdentifier": "my_id"}
{"userId": "my_user","externalUserId": "someone","logDirection": "INBOUND", "type": "RESPONSE","layerIdentifier": "my_id"}
```

As you say, the pattern `{ $.externalUserId IS NULL }` matches the first of these lines, the null. So it finds the inverse of what you want.

But all three of these patterns (which you suggested) match the second line when I try them in the debugger:

- `{ $.externalUserId = * }`
- `{ $.externalUserId != "blah" }`
- `{ $.externalUserId != "null" }`

Hence all three of the above should solve your problem of finding non-null values. They all correctly identify the log line where externalUserId is set to a string. The latter two are consistent with [OARP's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11598956/oarp) above comment that any use of `!=` in a pattern appears to do [an undocumented null check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70332210/8748686).

[The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) isn't super clear on this, but my read is that an asterisk in quotes (`"*"`) is the official method to match any string. In your case:

```
{ $.externalUserId = "*" }
```